# How could I say "when" in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am learning ActionScript 3 rigth now and I have this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouse_move);

function mouse_move(event:MouseEvent): void
{

    ourMirilla.x = mouseX * 1.85;
    ourMirilla.y = mouseY * 2 - 1244.25;
```

I would like to add something like this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouse_move);

function mouse_move(event:MouseEvent): void
{

    ourMirilla.x = mouseX * 1.85 WHEN MOUSEx IS (>35,<55);
    ourMirilla.y = mouseY * 2 - 1244.25 WHEN MOUSEy IS (>35,<55);
```

How could I express that in ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` and `when` are synonymous in this situation, so:

```
function mouse_move(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(mouseX > 35 && mouseX < 55)
    {
         ourMirilla.x = mouseX * 1.85;
    }

    if(mouseY > 35 && mouseY < 55)
    {
        ourMirilla.y = mouseY * 2 - 1244.25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marty, thanks for the answer. I copied and pasted this code, but it only works with the X value, the Y exe keeps moving all around the stage. Analising your code, I noticed that you wrote mouseX in the Y formula, did you do that in purpose or maybe that is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Rafa nah it's a typo sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**If statement**

The if statement asks a question. The associated code is executed only if the answer to that question is true. To write an if statement, start with if, followed by a set of parentheses around the conditional test you want to evaluate. Then use curly brackets to denote the code block you want to run if the condition is true.

```
if (ourMirilla.x > 10) {ourMirilla.alpha = 0.5);}
```

**The operators**

Conditional expressions frequently use the equality and comparison operators: == , !=, < , <= , > , >= . You can also use the logical operators: && (logical AND) and || (logical OR).

See [ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Operators](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html) for more information.

**Your code**

```
function mouse_move(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.stageX > 35 && e.stageX < 55) {ourMirilla.x = e.stageX * 1.85;}
    if (e.stageY > 35 && e.stageY < 55) {ourMirilla.y = e.stageY * 2 - 1244.25;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement inside your function like this

function .... 
if (MOUSEx IS (>35,<55)) 
do something ...

I am not familiar with language syntax, but this is the way how to add your When statement :)

[Here](http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/actionscript3/conditionals/) you can read about Conditional Statements